# TypeError: Cannot read property 'File' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload file to my firebase storage and have the url stored in database. I followed an example that i found on this [link](http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/angular-4-firebase-upload-file-to-storage). I have two different ts classes. I got an error in my `pushFileToStorage` function that said `TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined` when i hit the submit button. Can anyone help me solve this please?.

```js
//these are from two different class files
//fileUpload.ts
export class FileUpload {
  name: string;
  Url: string;
  File: File;

  constructor(prdFile: File) {
    this.prdFile = prdFile;
  }
}

//product.ts
export class Product {
  $prdKey: string;
  prdName: string;
  prdImage: string;
  prdDescription: string;
}
```

```js
//product.service.ts

basePath = '/Product';
pushFileToStorage(fileUpload: FileUpload, Product: Product, progress: {
  percentage: number
}) {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${fileUpload.File.name}`).put(fileUpload.File);

  uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    (snapshot) => {
      // in progress
      const snap = snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot
      progress.percentage = Math.round((snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100)
    },
    (error) => {
      // fail
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      // success
      this.productList.push({
        prdName: Product.prdName,
        prdImage: Product.prdImage = fileUpload.Url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL,
        prdDescription: Product.prdDescription,
      })
      this.saveFileData(fileUpload)
    }
  );
}

private saveFileData(fileUpload: FileUpload) {
  this.firebase.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(fileUpload);
}
```

```js
//product.component.ts
currentFileUpload: FileUpload;
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

  this.ProductService.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload, this.ProductService.selectedProduct, this.progress);
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `this.currentFileUpload` property in `product.component.ts` file?

Comment: like this `currentFileUpload: FileUpload;` CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

When you do `currentFileUpload: FileUpload;` you are not providing any value for it, you are only providing the type for `currentFileUpload`. The value will still be `undefined`. To initialize set it to an instance:

```
currentFileUpload: FileUpload = fileUploadInstance; // Get the instance somehow
```